# How to ¿connect? a website and a Java App

Tags: java, html, wordpress, tomcat, web-applications

This is just an introductory question for a problem that I'd be required to solve in the following weeks.

I have a website and a Java WebApp, both currently unrelated.

Website is BootStrap and Java App runs under Apache Tomcat.

The website is in one domain, and its core file is index.htm

The App is in other domain, and core is index.jsp, enclosed in a .war file

We will redesign the site , leave BootStrap and move to WordPress.

BUT, and this what I don't know how to do it, from the WordPress site I'd be required to LOGIN into Java App.

That is to create the typical user/pass miniform.

The web works at port 80, Java at 8080....   Any way, not being an expert is hard for me to imagine how to invoque Java Login from HTML, as the website is not going to be included inside the project.

I'm sure this is quite basic... Thank you!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a nice question you have.

I think the best solution is install a plugin in your wordpress project: `**https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api-auth**` 
with this plugin you can get a **rest api login** and then you only need to consume this api from your java application.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Luis I was out of the web a long time on family matters. Thank you for your answer! Surelly will try it in the near future.